# JavaFX, GridPane: Make elements in a column of a GridPane will all column width

Tags: java, javafx

```java
public class Tester extends Application  {
    private static final int WIDTH = 300;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 400;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        pane.setHgap(10);
        pane.setVgap(10);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

        pane.add(new Button("cat"), 0, 0);
        pane.add(new Button("monkey"), 0, 1);
        pane.add(new Button("elephant and lion"), 0, 2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

shows:

[image]

How do I make all buttons have the same width, like this:

[image]

I tried adding the buttons to a `VBox` and then adding the `VBox` to the `GridPane`, but it didn't work.

Comment: If your case is similar to your example, I would use `VBox`.

Comment: Study the [Oracle tips for sizing and aligning nodes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/size_align.htm#JFXLY133), it covers the topic of button sizing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case you need to set the maxWidth of the buttons to POSITIVE_INFINITY.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Tester extends Application {
    private static final int WIDTH = 300;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 400;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        pane.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        pane.setHgap(10);
        pane.setVgap(10);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

        Button cat = new Button("cat");
        Button monkey = new Button("monkey");
        Button elephant = new Button("elephant and lion");
        pane.add(cat, 0, 0);
        pane.add(monkey, 0, 1);
        pane.add(elephant, 0, 2);

        Stream.of(cat, monkey, elephant).forEach(btn -> btn.setMaxWidth(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY));

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```